# Crear formularios que aparezca y desaparezca en php

Tags: php7

esta pregunta es algo complicada pero no tengo idea de que conceptos o herramientas que se deben aplicar.

Tengo dos formularios en PHP y lo que quiero es que al mostrar la página se vea el formulario principal, y al presionar un botón o marcar un checkbox aparezca el segundo formulario y al llenar los campos de ambos con el mismo boton de enviar todos los datos sean almacenados en la base de datos, es decir el action tenga el efecto para los dos. A continuacion les muestro ambos formularios. 
Gracias de antemano

```
<div class="span6">
<div class="widget-box">
    <div class="widget-title"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-flag"></i></span>
        <h5>Registrar Sitios Geográficos</h5>                                        
        </div>
            <div class="widget-content nopadding">                                        
                <form action="../methods/InsertarDatosForms.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

                    <!--primer campo-->         
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Nombre del Sitio</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_sitio" placeholder="Sitio Geográfico">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--segundo campo-->  
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Ubicación del Sitio</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ubicacion_sitio" placeholder="Nombre del lugar">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
    <form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nombre de Sonda: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="Nombre de la Sonda" />
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Dispositivo: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="Tipo de dispositivo usado" />
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">No. de serie del dispositivo: </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="Número de serie" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Probaste utilizando `JQuery` para dar esa funcionalidad? es una buena alternativa :)

Comment: Gracias por responder @Paulo Urbano Rivera, si sabía que se puede utilizar, sin embargo no se como hacerlo, no tengo mucha experiencia en PHP y JQuery he visto menos. Tendrás algún ejemplo o algun tutorial donde pueda empezar? Por el momento comenzare con lo que me indicaste